# Creating a single column from 4 variables

Tags: r, multiple-columns

My data has targeted sanctions for each sanction year. There are 5 types of targeted sanctions, but as I am interested in looking at the sanctions overall and not their specific type I'd like to create a new column that represents whether overall targeted sanctions are imposed in a given year.

```
df1 <- data.frame(Country = 'Angola', 
              Asset_freeze = c(1, 0), 
              Sectoral = c(1, 0),
              Commodity = c(1, 0),
              Diplomatic = c(1, 0),
              Individual = c(1, 0), 
              Year = c('1993', '1994', '1995')

  Country Asset_freeze Sectoral Commodity Diplomatic Individual  Year
    (chr)        (dbl)    (dbl)     (dbl)      (dbl)      (dbl) (int)
1 Angola             0        1         1          0          0  1993
2 Angola             0        1         1          0          0  1994
3 Angola             0        1         1          0          0  1995
```

I would like it to look like the following:

```
     Country          Year   Sanctions
    (chr)             (int)     (dbl)
1 Angola               1993       1
2 Angola               1994       1
3 Angola               1995       1
```

How could i get this? Thanks

Comment: In which case would `Sanctions` be 0 ?

Comment: Your input dataset code is giving me errorss

Comment: Could you phrase your question with more focus on the coding issue rather than the specific issue you're applying it to?  We shouldn't need to interpret what you mean by sanctions.  Do you mean whether there are any non-zero entries in the middle five columns for each year?  @akrun: I think it is a missing bracket at the end.

Comment: Basically all these sanctions would be coded as 1 because this dataset represent countries and years that the UN has imposed targeted sanctions. However I am merging it with a dataset that represents GNI per capita in these countries and has a lot more countries so i would then code those as 0.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can rowwise sum(`rowSums`) the columns involving 5 types of `Sanctions` and check if any of the sanction is imposed and then convert the boolean values to numeric using `as.numeric`

```
cbind(df1[c("Country", "Year")], Sanctions = as.numeric(rowSums(df1[, 2:6]) > 0))


#   Country Year Sanctions
#1  Angola 1993         1
#2  Angola 1994         1
#3  Angola 1995         1
```

Answer (score 2):

You could also use a combination of `cbind`, `apply` and `ifelse`:

```
cbind(df1[,c(1,7)], Sanctions=apply(df1[,2:6], 1, function(x) {
    ifelse(any(x==1), 1, 0)
}))

 Country Year Sanctions
 Angola  1993 1        
 Angola  1994 1        
 Angola  1995 1
```

As suggested by @Bazz, this could have been shortened by doing the following:

```
cbind(df1[,c(1,7)], Sanctions=as.numeric(apply(df1[,2:6], 1, any)))
```

Here, the columns are selected by index number and not by name. But if you want, you could easily grab the columns by name.

I hope this helps.

Comment: You could simply have `apply(df1[,2:6], 1, any)`.  The output would be logical rather than integer.

Comment: I was trying to avoid providing a solution that generates `warnings`. Also, it's just more explicit to show what's going on. But I will make sure to edit the answer.

Answer (score 2):

You can use `dplyr` and the resulting command conveys what you want to achieve:

```
library(dplyr)
df1 %>% group_by(Country, Year) %>% 
        mutate(Sanctions = as.numeric(any(Asset_freeze, Sectoral, Commodity, Diplomatic, Individual))) %>% 
        select(Country, Year, Sanctions)
##  Country   Year Sanctions
##   <fctr> <fctr>     <dbl>
##1  Angola   1993         1
##2  Angola   1994         1
##3  Angola   1995         1
```

Answer (score 2):

We could use `pmax` for the columns 2:6 and it should automatically pick up the max value

```
cbind(df1[c("Country", "Year")], Sanctions = do.call(pmax, df1[2:6]))
#    Country Year Sanctions
#1  Angola 1993         1
#2  Angola 1994         1
#3  Angola 1995         1
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `data.table`:

```
require(data.table)

setDT(df1)

NSanc <- 5L

df1[, list(Sanctions = do.call(any, .SD)),
    by = c("Country", "Year"),
    .SDcols = 2:(NSanc + 1)]
```

NSanc is the number of sanction types.